# Typo3 Extbase filter by sys category

Tags: filter, typo3, categories, extbase

Hello I enabled Categories for my extbase extension with

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::makeCategorizable
```

Works fine but how do I filter Elements to be shown in frontend so a backend user can chose a category for the plugin element?

Comment: You mean "how can a backend user chose a category for the plugin element so it filters Elements to be shown in frontend"?

Comment: can you please add some more description,because not getting exactly what do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Add a FlexForm.
To do this, add this to your ext_tables.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'Vendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Pluginname',
    'My plugin description as shown to the backend user'
);
$pluginSignature = strtolower(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::underscoredToUpperCamelCase($_EXTKEY)) . '_pluginname';
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/myflexform.xml');
```

Configure the flexform so you can select a category:

```
<T3DataStructure>
    <sheets>
        <settings>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Settings</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <settings.myCategory>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <label>Category</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>group</type>
                                <internal_type>db</internal_type>
                                <allowed>sys_category</allowed>
                                <foreign_table>sys_category</foreign_table>
                                <size>1</size>
                                <minitems>0</minitems>
                                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.myCategory>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </settings>
    </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

See here for reference: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/DataFormats/T3datastructure/Index.html

Then use that value in your Controller Action like `$this->settings['myCategory']` and pass it to your query in the repository.